# Anyone know how to fix "Can't resolve symbol 'Inject'" error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, windows, android-studio, gradlew

I'm having a problem when Android Studio v0.3.5 where the symbol 'Inject' isn't recognized.

I have the following: `import javax.inject.Inject;` where the whole line is greyed out except for Inject where it's red. The greyed out part gives me a hint that it's an unsused import, but the red part gives me a cannot resolve symbol error.

So I followed the instruction here-> [Android Studio: Add jar as library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library) , but without any success.  I get the following error when I do a `gradlew clean`.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\dovailla\AndroidStudioProjects\BootstrapProject\build.gradle' line: 2

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'BootstrapProject'.
> Could not find method compile() for arguments [file collection] on root project 'BootstrapProject'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.093 secs
```

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 11):

javax.inject isn't part of the Android Java library, so you'll need to pull that in from an external library. You might find some more help at [Android Roboguice Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251367/android-roboguice-exception)

Note that the answers there tend to have you download a jar, put it in your libs directory, and access it that way; you may find it more convenient to use a Maven-style dependency declaration, similar to:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar'
}
```

Looking at the error message from your build, I think it's a syntax error in your build.gradle file -- did you put your `compile files(...)` statement in your `dependencies` block?